# iOS: navigating between views

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.3

I'm looking for a good place where I can find tutorial/documentation with samples about the different ways to switch between views (viewcontrollers), also I'm interested in the different possibilities of of the animation we can perform.

So does any body have some links ?

E-Books are very appreciated  :)

Comment: Switching between views depend upon your requirement.What is your requirement?

Comment: I wanted to have something in general, I don't have anything specail in minde, just wanted to learn the different possible ways so when ever I need something I can say if it EXISTS or not, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Dude You can Simple Refere [uinavigationcontroller class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of Apple Document.

Comment: even if its not answer my question 100% but in somehow I could manage to get some information, thanks a lot :)